# Can the Black still win the game? How?

Tags: analysis, learning, middlegame

It’s Black to move.

```
[FEN "r3k2r/pppbn2p/4p1p1/8/3PNq2/2PB2P1/PP3P1P/R2QR1K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

[Here's a picture of a groovy little portable chess set with the position above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep8xH.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Black is pretty well busted.  His minor pieces are inferior to White's. His Queen has few squares and will end up on f7, f8, or h6. He has not yet castled.  Plus he's down a pawn and has an isolated e-pawn whose weakness is accentuated by the uncastled King.

White has a grasp on the center, good pawns, a castled King, and a Rook on the best file. I don't care for the fianchetto'd g-pawn with the light-squared Black Bishop and Queen on the board, but if Black can't exploit it then it does not matter.

Stockfish isn't very excited about Black's chances and believes the game to be decisively won by White:

```
[FEN "r3k2r/pppbn2p/4p1p1/8/3PNq2/2PB2P1/PP3P1P/R2QR1K1 b q - 2 2"]

2... Qf7 3.Qb3 O-O-O 4.Ng5 Qf8 5.Nxe6 Bxe6 6.Rxe6 Nc6 7.Ba6 bxa6 8.Rxc6 Rd6 9.Qc4 Rxc6 10.Qxc6 Qe8 11.Qxa6+ Kb8 12.Rd1 Rf8 13.d5 Qe7 14.Qb5+ Kc8 15.Qc4 Qd6 16.Kg2 h6 17.Qe2 Kd8 18.Qe3 Qb6 19.Re1 Qxe3
```

With a score of +4.2.  None of those moves look too hard to find, and I'd wager White can find good moves easier than Black.

Answer (score 2):

Black is losing by one pawn but the e6 shall fall as well , so white will lead by 2 pawns. in that case white would be winning by in chess anything is possible, it's difficult for black to win but maybe you can confuse your opponent and get ahead in the game

Answer (score 2):

How much time is remaining for each color? If black has substantially more time than white and white is about to run out of time then black is likely to win.

Assuming this is a person vs person game and time is not part of the equation the answer has got to be yes, black can still win.

Two things are certain. One is that as of yet, there is no forced mate. So the game could go either way depending on what mistakes are made. The second is that if black quits, black cannot win.

How does black win? By not quiting and playing the rest of the game better than white while white makes mistakes. If black is better at the end game than white is and white makes mistakes black can still win.

If this is computer vs computer I think the answer is no. Black won't win.

If this is person vs computer and the computer is strong and playing white I think the answer is no.

Of course there are other possibilities too. The best way to find out is by finishing the game.

Answer (score 0):

Objectively, black is lost but that's not the question you asked. You asked if it was possible that black could someone win the game. Obviously, the answer is yes. Theoretically white could drop his queen on the next move.

I think black's best chances are to consolidate his pieces, castle queenside and use the weak light squares to generate an attack.